# components in .vuepress/components folder doesn't render

Tags: vuepress

I try to add a simple vue component for using it in .md file as explain in the vuepress documentation. I placed my HelloWord.vue in the .vuepress/components folder and then in my markdown file i call it with  but nothing show up after running vuepress dev, does anyone had this problem before ?

Answer (score 0):

How are you writing the component in your `.md` file?

For a component called `HelloWorld.vue` in `.vuepress/components`, you need to use:

`<HelloWorld />` or `<hello-world />`

if it's in a subfolder inside components, you need to prepend that to your component name and I believe you then have to ensure you use the same format as the components file name.

So for a `HelloWorld.vue` component stored in `./vuepress/components/example/`, you would use:

`<example-HelloWorld />`

Comment: Hey Frank, u gave me a good tip because <hello-world /> works but not <HelloWorld /> it's crazy !! but now its working this way, im not sure i can make this issue solved though !

Answer (score 0):

Vuejs seems to follow this rule :

kebab-case such as `<hello-world />` is accepted by default in HTML files (md files too since they will be rendered as HTML).

However, if you specify the name of the component in your .vue file, as follows :

```
<script>
export default {
name : 'PreviewPage'
}
</script>
```

Then, both `<HelloWorld />` and `<hello-world />` will be recognized.