# how to add a component in VuePress v.2.0.0?

Tags: vue.js, components, vuepress

I am using VuePress version:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "vuepress": "^2.0.0-beta.26"
}
```

and I can't add a simple .vue component to my .md page.

My Github [LINK](http://github.com/DariuszLegizynski/VuepressTest)

Tried out the other solutions here, but nothing seems to help:
[Solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51987732/vuepress-how-to-custom-location-of-components-directory-vuepress-components)
[Solution2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55125776/components-in-vuepress-components-folder-doesnt-render)

I was following the guide from the official [VuePress documentation](https://v2.vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/markdown.html#components) about components. But all I get is a zero size component (no content shown)

[image]

Would really appreciate any solutions.

EDIT:

to make it a bit simpler than to check my github. The whole project contains anyway only 2 files.

So what I did, is to make a new component.vue file in .vuepress/components:

```
<template>
<h1>Hello from my test component</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {}
</script>

<style></style>
```

and am trying to add it in my README.md file:

```
# Hello VuePress

### test component

<TestComponent />

<kebab-case-test-component />
```

Screenshot for my folder tree:

[image]

Comment: would like to add a codesanbox link but this just wan't do it. Here is my github link: https://github.com/DariuszLegizynski/VuepressTest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [VuePress 1.x to 2.x migration docs](https://v2.vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/migration.html#conventional-files-change):

> #### .vuepress/components/
>
> Files in this directory will not be registered as Vue components automatically.
>
> You need to use [@vuepress/plugin-register-components](https://v2.vuepress.vuejs.org/reference/plugin/register-components.html), or register your components manually in `.vuepress/clientAppEnhance.{js,ts}`.

To configure auto component registration:

1. Install the [`@vuepress/plugin-register-components`](https://v2.vuepress.vuejs.org/reference/plugin/register-components.html) plugin:

   ```
   npm i -D @vuepress/plugin-register-components@next
   ```
2. Add `.vuepress/config.js` with the following contents:

   ```js
   const { path } = require('@vuepress/utils')

   module.exports = {
     plugins: [
       [
         '@vuepress/register-components',
         {
           componentsDir: path.resolve(__dirname, './components'),
         },
       ],
     ],
   }
   ```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vuepress-auto-reg-components?file=docs%2FREADME.md)

Comment: Since [april 2022](https://github.com/vuepress/vuepress-next/commit/b85b1c3b39e80a8de92a7469381061f75ef33623) the config API seems to have changed. See [this documentation page](https://v2.vuepress.vuejs.org/reference/plugin/register-components.html#componentsdir) for updated way of setting components dir.